# Valgrind captures SIGSEGV on std::string destructor

Tags: c++, linux, string, c++11, valgrind

I've been trying to debug a comparatively infrequent, impossible-to-produce-on-demand [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013592/valgrind-supplying-question-marks) [issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214622/which-process-wrote-to-which-memory-address) for some time now, and I think today provided the most useful `valgrind` output thus far. Below are the relevant lines:

```
==25808== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==25808==    at 0x4EF14CE: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==25808==    by 0x491EA7: app::symbol_parameters::~symbol_parameters() (App.h:26)
==25808==    by 0x4B7E04: app::AddSymbol(std::string, int, unsigned long) (xyz_symbol_add.cpp:43)
==25808==    by 0x4B3269: AppStartup(int, char**, char const*) (AppBase.cpp:332)
==25808==    by 0x48CE74: main (App.cpp:54)
==25808== 
==25808== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==25808==    at 0x4E9264D: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==25808==    by 0x4EF14DE: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==25808==    by 0x491EA7: app::symbol_parameters::~symbol_parameters() (App.h:26)
==25808==    by 0x4B7E04: app::AddSymbol(std::string, int, unsigned long) (xyz_symbol_add.cpp:43)
==25808==    by 0x4B3269: AppStartup(int, char**, char const*) (AppBase.cpp:332)
==25808==    by 0x48CE74: main (App.cpp:54)
==25808== 
==25808== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==25808==    at 0x4C2C272: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==25808==    by 0x4EF14DE: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==25808==    by 0x491EA7: app::symbol_parameters::~symbol_parameters() (App.h:26)
==25808==    by 0x4B7E04: app::AddSymbol(std::string, int, unsigned long) (xyz_symbol_add.cpp:43)
==25808==    by 0x4B3269: AppStartup(int, char**, char const*) (AppBase.cpp:332)
==25808==    by 0x48CE74: main (App.cpp:54)
==25808== 
==25808== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==25808==    at 0x4C2C2BC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==25808==    by 0x4EF14DE: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==25808==    by 0x491EA7: app::symbol_parameters::~symbol_parameters() (App.h:26)
==25808==    by 0x4B7E04: app::AddSymbol(std::string, int, unsigned long) (xyz_symbol_add.cpp:43)
==25808==    by 0x4B3269: AppStartup(int, char**, char const*) (AppBase.cpp:332)
==25808==    by 0x48CE74: main (App.cpp:54)
==25808==  Address 0x5c343e8 is in the Data segment of /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
==25808== 
==25808== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==25808==    at 0x4EF14CE: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==25808==    by 0x491EC7: app::symbol_parameters::~symbol_parameters() (App.h:26)
==25808==    by 0x4B7E04: app::AddSymbol(std::string, int, unsigned long) (xyz_symbol_add.cpp:43)
==25808==    by 0x4B3269: AppStartup(int, char**, char const*) (AppBase.cpp:332)
==25808==    by 0x48CE74: main (App.cpp:54)
==25808== 
==25808== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==25808==    at 0x4E9264D: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==25808==    by 0x4EF14DE: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==25808==    by 0x491EC7: app::symbol_parameters::~symbol_parameters() (App.h:26)
==25808==    by 0x4B7E04: app::AddSymbol(std::string, int, unsigned long) (xyz_symbol_add.cpp:43)
==25808==    by 0x4B3269: AppStartup(int, char**, char const*) (AppBase.cpp:332)
==25808==    by 0x48CE74: main (App.cpp:54)
==25808== 
==25808== 
==25808== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==25808==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x58EF4D4
==25808==    at 0x4E9264D: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==25808==    by 0x4EF14DE: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==25808==    by 0x491EC7: app::symbol_parameters::~symbol_parameters() (App.h:26)
==25808==    by 0x4B7E04: app::AddSymbol(std::string, int, unsigned long) (xyz_symbol_add.cpp:43)
==25808==    by 0x4B3269: AppStartup(int, char**, char const*) (AppBase.cpp:332)
==25808==    by 0x48CE74: main (App.cpp:54)
```

And here are the lines about which `valgrind` most directly complains:

App.h:26-40

```
struct symbol_parameters
{
  string   symbol;
  //...
};
```

xyz_symbol_add.cpp:18-43

```
struct symbol_parameters
{
  string   symbol;
};
//...
void AddSymbol(string sym, int32_t psn, uint64_t pr)
{
  string symb=format_symbol_local(sym);

  //...

  symbol_parameters p{symb};

  //...
```

And here's `format_symbol_local()`

```
string format_symbol_local(string symbol)
{
  // convert .PR to - 
  size_t found = symbol.find(".PR");
  if(string::npos==found) return symbol;
  return symbol.replace(found,3,"-");
}
```

AppBase.cpp:327-333

```
for(LibAbcCallBack::Position position : xyz_params.position_list)
{
  if(position.quantity > 0)
  {
    AddSymbol(position.symbol, position.quantity);
  }
}
```

And finally, App.cpp:54 is just a line from `main()`, calling `AppStartup()`. Nothing surprising there.

While there are names for most of the functions that `valgrind` takes issue with, I'm having a hard time deriving anything useful from the output. Where should I be looking from here?

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but you're not passing 3 arguments to AddSymbol()

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. It defaults to zero in the declaration. =)

Comment: Try to skim it down to a complete, minimal verifiable example. This might be hard, but during that you could find the bug. This screams undefined behaviour for me, which is impossible to find using the few snippets you provide.

Comment: From the output I'd guess that the destructor of a string that hasn't been initialised is called. Do you have unions or placement new in your code?

Comment: Why do you have that struct definition (`symbol_parameters`) both in your header and source file?

Comment: I don't have an answer for the duplicate `struct` definitions, but I'll look into that. Otherwise, I wasn't able to find any placement `new`s, and there are three `union`s in our code and one in the third party code (but they're all primitives; no `string`s).

Comment: Hm ... what are the parameters `AppStartup` is called with? How is the string created that is passed to `AddSymbol`?

Comment: `int AlgoStartup(int argc, char** argv, const char* APP_VERSION)` and it's being called with `main()`'s params plus a string literal. `AddSymbol()` is being fed a string that's coming in from the third party library. They create a vector of `struct`s (one `string` and one `double`) that we copy over in the callback for the event. So I can't grab the string's original construction, but it is being copied over at least.

Comment: I agree with Daniel. The duplicate struct definition is highly suspicious, especially since your `//...` placement seems to suggest that they don't match. (Do they?)

Comment: We've gone some weeks now without seeing this issue, so I'm inclined to tick an answer. But, since we never got to one formally, I've just upvoted the two remarks on duplicate definitions. It appears that this was indeed the root of the issue.